# Configuring JanusGraph with Lucene as index backend and HBase or Cassandra as storage backend

Tags: cassandra, lucene, hbase, janusgraph

How can I configure Janusgraph with Lucene as index backend and Cassandra/HBase as storage backend?

When running this command

`./bin/janusgraph-server.sh console ./conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-[...].yaml`

It only starts up Janusgraph if we use `gremlin-server-berkeleyje.yaml` and set the configuration as `janusgraph-berkeleyje-lucene.properties`. Other attempts to use Lucene with supported storage backends throw errors on Janusgraph startup related to setting up index backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lucene indexing backend cannot support multiple cooperating JanusGraph instances. Therefore, using JanusGraph with Lucene only makes sense when using the Berkeleyje storage backend, which has the same limitation.

Note that you can use JanusGraph without indexing backend. Then, it is still possible to configure so-called [Composite Indices](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/#composite-index) for equality lookups. This might be the easiest way for you to get going if you have a HBase/Cassandra cluster available, but are still missing an Elasticsearch/Solr cluster.